# How to filter and get specific keys from JSON objects array

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-13, json-path

I have a JSONB field containing a value in this structure:

```
[
    {
        "type": "small",
        "name": "Josh",
        "greeting": "Hello buddy!",
        "hobby": "billiards",
        "place": "Barcelona"
    },
    {
        "type": "big",
        "name": "Aziz",
        "greeting": "Hey man!",
        "hobby": "tennis",
        "place": "Montpellier"
    }
]
```

I want to include this output if `type` is equal to "big":

```
{
    "greeting": "Hey man! How're you doing Aziz?",
    "place": "Montpellier"
}
```

1. In the first row, I combined two values into one with some additional words.
2. I don't want my whole output to be empty if there isn't `type` value
   equal to "big".  Instead, output values of `type` value equal to
   "small" as a fallback.
3. If there is not a fallback with `type` equal to "small", then output an empty string or `NULL` value but without Nulling the whole query result. Or preferably, not include these keys if no value is present.

I know I can combine values into one by using `CONCAT` but don't know how to build this query and integrate it. I can't loop through the `array` and output the values of the `object` that matches my filter. Tried `CASE` but still wasn't able to get the result I want.

I use PostgreSQL 13.

Answer (score 1):

Returns single column of JSON if big or small exists, NULL otherwise:

```
WITH records AS (
  SELECT * FROM JSONB_TO_RECORDSET(
    '[
        {
            "type": "small",
            "name": "Josh",
            "greeting": "Hello buddy!",
            "hobby": "billiards",
            "place": "Barcelona"
        },
        {
            "type": "big",
            "name": "Aziz",
            "greeting": "Hey man!",
            "hobby": "tennis",
            "place": "Montpellier"
        }
      ]'
  ) as record(type VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, greeting VARCHAR, hobby VARCHAR, place VARCHAR)
)
SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'greeting', FORMAT('%s How''re doing %s?', greeting, name),
        'place', place
       )
FROM records
WHERE type IN ('big', 'small')
ORDER BY type
LIMIT 1;
```